# What is the value of $a + b + c + d$ if the following equation holds?

Tags: linear-algebra, diophantine-equations

If $a, b, c$ and $d$ are positive integers less than $7$ and
$$a(7)^3 + b(7)^2 + c(7) + d = 901$$
What is the value of $a + b + c + d$?

Is it related to consum of roots and product of roots?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

HINT:

Clearly, the Left hand Side represents a number in base $7$

Reference : [Base Conversion](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base_conversion#Base_conversion)

So, $\displaystyle a=\lfloor901/{7^3}\rfloor$